# Do cars which have had recent engine rebuilds tend to be low in or keep their value?

Tags: engine

I was looking at this car on ebay:  https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Honda-Civic-Coupe-VTi-EM1-DOHC-B16A2/293258756385?hash=item4447958121:g:kwEAAOSwCH9dlPAa
It looks in exceptional condition and well looked after from how new all the parts look under the hood.  However it sold for quite a lot cheaper than I would expect.

I notice it has done 1000 miles since a receipt and pictures verifiable engine rebuild.  Is that the reason why it would have gone for cheaper despite all other parts of the car looking so good i.e. it had an engine rebuild.  Do people typically think rebuild may not have been done properly so engine might have problems later and so they prefer cars on the original engine and a hence a rebuilt doesn't tend to increase or keep the sale value of a car?  Im just wondering why this went for so low and this is the only thing I can think of.  I know the car didnt have mot for 3 previous years but thats consistent with his story that he was waiting for someone to do an engine rebuild.

Anyway I'm just wondering if this is it.

Comment: Was the receipt indicating an individual did it themselves or was it done professionally?

Comment: Not just a rebuild. Previous owner resprayed it (why - accident damage?), low mileage (only 5000/year) but "lots of repairs", off the road for two years, rare model, 19 years old - too many red flags if you just want a reliable car to use every day, too many question marks in its history if you want a potential "classic car".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many factors going into the final sale price of a used vehicle. For engine rebuilds/replacements:

- Given a particular make and model, what is the expected time between engine rebuilds? The car in question only has 100k miles. If the engine was replaced at a relatively low mileage, why did it fail in the first place? Was the car driven roughly? What other kinds of problems might it have?
- What exactly was the problem with the engine? The car in question received a rebuild of the engine, not a replacement. Some engines are worn/damaged to the point of a rebuild not fixing them correctly. The car might be fine for a short period of time and then revert to old problems like oil/coolant burning, etc.
- A car that has been driven a certain number of miles is often assumed to have "proven itself" to not have major issues. Having a rebuilt engine is somewhat like having a brand new car where the owner doesn't know if there are some unexpected problems with the vehicle that haven't surfaced yet.

Besides the engine, the car in question has a number of modifications. Some modifications, even though they cost money to make, reduce the value of the vehicle for a particular buyer.

Comment: This has so many questions in it...